# Can a different partial.scss file be loaded every time a different customer logs in at runtime for angular application?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, material-design, themes

Working on a multicustomer project build with angular and material theming, where each customer wants to have their own theme.
the themes are to be stored on s3 buckets so the customer has access to them and can change customizable theme options as per their preference.
the application will be deployed as a single instance for all these customers, however, the theme should change as per the customer logged in. 
the theme change will occur after the application is bootstrapped as we need to fetch the logged in customer's details and based on that retrieve respective theme from s3 bucket.

is this approach possible? any reference for this sort of implementation?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Check this link https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-lazy-load-css-at-runtime-with-the-angular-cli